# Problem with setting margins length in MFC

Tags: c++, winapi, printing, mfc, windows-ce

How to set margins in this code
It I should similar construction likie DriverName, DeviceName, OutputName?
Actually program are compiling but settings of margins doesn't works.
I have no idea why?

It is MFC project

```
    BOOL Druk::Configuration()
{
    //CPageSetupDialog psd;
    //CPageSetupDialog psd(PSD_MARGINS | PSD_INTHOUSANDTHSOFINCHES, NULL);
    //PAGESETUPDLG m_psd;
    ZeroMemory(&psd, sizeof(psd));
    psd.lStructSize = sizeof(psd); // psd is member of PAGESETUPDLG structure
    psd.hwndOwner = NULL;
    psd.hDevMode = NULL; // Don't forget to free or store hDevMode.
    psd.hDevNames = NULL; // Don't forget to free or store hDevNames.
    psd.Flags = PSD_INTHOUSANDTHSOFINCHES | PSD_MARGINS;
    psd.rtMargin.top = 2000;
    psd.rtMargin.left = 2000;
    psd.rtMargin.right = 2000;
    psd.rtMargin.bottom = 2000;
    //psd.rtMinMargin.bottom = 5000;
    lf_vertic.lfHeight = 30; // is member of LOGFONT structure
    lf_vertic.lfWidth = 0;
    //lf.lfOrientation = 2700;
    lf_vertic.lfEscapement = 0;
    lf_vertic.lfUnderline = FALSE;
    lf_vertic.lfWeight = FW_BOLD;
    lf_horizont.lfHeight = 30;
    lf_horizont.lfWidth = 0;
    //lf.lfOrientation = 2700;
    lf_horizont.lfEscapement = 2700;
    lf_horizont.lfUnderline = FALSE;
    lf_horizont.lfWeight = FW_BOLD;

    lf_exam_param.lfHeight = 30;
    lf_exam_param.lfWidth = 0;
    lf_exam_param.lfEscapement = 2700;
    lf_exam_param.lfUnderline = FALSE;
    lf_exam_param.lfWeight = FW_NORMAL;

    hFontVertic = CreateFontIndirect(&lf_vertic);
    hFontHorizont = CreateFontIndirect(&lf_horizont);
    hFontExamParam = CreateFontIndirect(&lf_exam_param);
    if (PageSetupDlg(&psd) == TRUE)
    //if (IDOK == psd.DoModal())
    {
        memcpy(&dm, (DEVMODE *)(psd.hDevMode), sizeof(DEVMODE));
        lstrcpy(DriverName, ((TCHAR *)((BYTE *)psd.hDevNames + ((DEVNAMES *)psd.hDevNames)->wDriverOffset)));
        lstrcpy(DeviceName, ((TCHAR *)((BYTE *)psd.hDevNames + ((DEVNAMES *)psd.hDevNames)->wDeviceOffset)));
        lstrcpy(OutputName, ((TCHAR *)((BYTE *)psd.hDevNames + ((DEVNAMES *)psd.hDevNames)->wOutputOffset)));
        lstrcpy(OutputName, ((TCHAR *)((BYTE *)psd.hDevNames + ((DEVNAMES *)psd.hDevNames)->wOutputOffset)));
        //lstrcpy(BottomMargin, psd.rtMargin + ((DEVNAMES *)psd.hDevNames)->wOutputOffset)));
    }
    //error = CommDlgExtendedError();
    return TRUE;
    
}
```

Comment: Not sure if the result I got are consistent with you. I use "Microsoft Print to PDF" to output PDF file and set the margins in the code. There is indeed a problem that the margins of the pdf files are not changed.

Comment: `settings of margins doesn't works`  Can you see the changes in page margins on Page Setup? See [it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7fQ7.png).

Comment: I have no page preview in PageSetupDlg dialog box

Comment: Another question, how did you make sure that the margin settings are not working. Have you tested it on a real printer?

Comment: I used Windows 10 for a print test and the preview page can be seen. When I change the size of the margins, the margins of the preview page will change accordingly. You seem to be using windows CE, and most of the CE versions have stopped supporting. Refer [Search product lifecycle](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search/1143).

Comment: You can also [send Feedback on this topic to the authors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/ms911910(v=msdn.10)#see-also).

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT Yes, I tested it on real printer

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT Look on the fact that i use WinCE 2013 system.

Comment: Have you tested `PageSetupDlg` on Windows 10? If everything is normal on win10, then the problem may be Windows CE. I suggest waiting for community members who are experienced in Wndows CE to answer this question.